# Summoning PrimedTnt with custom fuselengths

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I summon PrimedTnt with a custom fuse length? I know I have to add some attributes to it, but I'm not sure as to how I can do that. Does anyone know? Also, is there a way to turn TNT explosion damage? I already know how to summon PrimedTnt, like this:

```
/summon PrimedTnt <relative coords>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

adding {Fuse:x} to the end of the command will add a custom fuse time however, x can only be replaced by numbers up to 127, 128 and above will detonate the TNT Instantly. Here's an example:

```
/summon PrimedTnt <relative coords> {Fuse:<amount of ticks>}
```

Answer (score 0):

## 1.12 Update

- `PrimedTnt` has been changed to `tnt`. So the new command is:

  ```
  /summon tnt 1 2 3 {Fuse:80}
  ```

to summon a TNT block at coordinates 1, 2, 3 with a fuse of 4 seconds.

- Maximum fuse is 32767 ticks, or 00:27:18.35.